# underlying connection failed to open

Tags: mysql, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application and in one of the controllers i have this set

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

so that my ajax calls are processed in parallel.

I write the session in all of the methods for the ajax calls (Session["variable"] = something) but never with the same key("variable" is different in all the methods).

The problem is that if the number of ajax calls exceeds 10 i sometimes get this error "underlying connection failed to open". For the database I use **SQL Server Management Studio 2008**

I researched the error but in all the posts this error always appears, not just sometimes as in my case.

I found this setting **Min Pool Size** which if i set to 10 seems to fix my problem, but my worry is overhead and that this won't solve my problem if there are let's say 20 users that use that page at the same time.

My question is, is it safe to set the **Min Pool Size** in my connection string and will this suffice for a larger number of users(not just 1) or can you point me in the right direction for a good solution?